# compare tuple element from keys of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary and the key of the dictionary is a tuple. I want to compare all the keys in the dictionary by comparing all the elements inside the tuple to get the haming distance.

my dictionary is as following:

```
dic={(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1):8, (1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0):48, ....}
```

I have tried to do:

```
haming_dist = [[0]*(len(dic)) for i in range(len(dic))]
for i in range(len(dic)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(dic)):
        count=0
        for k in range(10):
            if dic[i][k] != dic[j][k]:
                count=count+1
        haming_dist[i][j]=count
```

but it didn't work. Also I have tried to write `list(dic[i])[k]`, `tuple(dic[i])[k]` and `tuple(dic[i])` but nothing worked. What is the right way?

Comment: What are you trying to do, count how many each unique tuple is present? Or just count the number of unique tuples?

Comment: i want to calculate the distance between each key and another by counting the number of non similar element from the tuple. the distance between the tuple (1,0,0) and (1,1,1) is 2.

Comment: And how would you want to store it? I imagine that in a dict, but what would be the key to that dict?

Comment: Do the keys have different lengths?

Comment: Actually i want to caluclate the haming distance between those keys and all the keys are from the same length.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a bit confused. You're trying to get the `i`th and `j`th keys of the dict, but you can't do that - dictionaries aren't ordered. What you can do is get the keys of the dict as a list, and then iterate through that. Try this:

```
keys = list(dic)

for i in range(len(keys)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(keys)):
        count = 0
        for k in range(10):
            if keys[i][k] != keys[j][k]:
                count += 1
        print "Distance from %s to %s is %d" % (keys[i], keys[j], count)
```